# Vert.x RxJava and Reactive Streams API

Tags: rx-java, vert.x, project-reactor, reactive-streams

I am new to Vert.x and currently exploring it. I found that in vert.x 3 there are three ways to use 
1) Using normal vertex API
2) Using RxJava based API
3) Using Reactive Streams based API

I want to know whether all vertex modules are available in RxJava and Reactive Streams API or there are still some modules where reactive version is not available?
Also what can be the shortcomings of using either #2 or #3 against #1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Reactive Streams based API. There is a Vert.x Reactive Streams module, which simply bridges Vert.x `ReadStream` with Reactive Streams `Publisher`, and `WriteStream` with `Subscriber`.

Vert.x core as well as all modules in the stack have an *Rxified* API. This means all methods working with callbacks will either return a `Single`, `Completable` or `Maybe`. `ReadStream` can be converted to `Flowable` or `Observable`.

A few methods from the Vert.x core and modules API are not available in the *Rxified* API, but you can easily convert an *Rxified* Vert.x object to its core counterpart with [`getDelegate`](https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/reactivex/core/Vertx.html#getDelegate--) method.

Comment: I could see that for eg AMQP Bridge, there are two options in reactive way one is io.vertx.reactivex.amqpbridge or other is io.vertx.rxjava.amqpbridge . I wanted to know the differences in using either of these

Comment: The former is the RxJava2 API, the latter RxJava1